# Count Total products of Opencart including options

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I want to calculate total count of products also when if a product has different sizes it count as different i.e for example : for product SKU1, I have different sizes like S, M, L, XL so the count will be 4 not 1.

tried this query but not working -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total 
  FROM oc_product p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN oc_product_option_value pov 
    ON pov.product_id = p.product_id
   AND pov.option_id in (5,11,12,13) 
  LEFT 
  JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s 
    ON p.product_id = p2s.product_id
 WHERE p.status = 1 
   AND p2s.store_id = 1
```

it's not giving correct count value. Can anyone help. I am new to Opencart.

oc_product table : { productId, name, status}

oc_product_option_value table : { productOptionValueId, productId, optionId, optionValueId, quantity }

optionId is for type like size, weight etc.
optionValueId id for sizes like S, M, L, XL etc.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  .. the expected  result and you actual result

Comment: Try to change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(p.id)`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hey, I have already tried as COUNT(p.id). Not working.@J.Litvak

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `LEFT JOIN` for `oc_product_option_value`, you need a sub-query.

This works for me in OpenCart 3.0.2.0

```
SELECT COUNT(p.product_id) +
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oc_product_option_value pov WHERE pov.option_id = 11) AS total
  FROM oc_product p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s 
    ON p.product_id = p2s.product_id
 WHERE
 (SELECT DISTINCT(pov.product_id) FROM oc_product_option_value pov WHERE pov.product_id = p.product_id) IS NULL
 AND p.status = 1 
 AND p2s.store_id = 1
```